# Asp.net lazy loading related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Asp.net vs 2012 my classes are

```
public class klasa
{
    [Key]
    public int klasaid { get; set; }
    public string emriklases { get; set; }
    public string vendodhja { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<student> students { get; set; }
}
public class student
{
    [Key]
    public int studentid { get; set; }
    public string emristudent { get; set; }
    public int nota { get; set; }
    public int klasaid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("klasaid")]
    public klasa Klasa { get; set; }
```

Student List Controller

```
udb _db = new udb();
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="klsasaid")] int klasaid)
{
    var studentlist = _db.Seuni.Find(klasaid);
    if (studentlist != null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

StudentList View Index

```
@model Unilast.Models.klasa
<h2>List for @Model.emriklases </h2>
@Html.Partial("_partial1", @Model.students);
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
```

_partial1 view as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Unilast.Models.student>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emristudent)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nota)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.klasaid)
```

Lazy loading entities does not work.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'klasaid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'Unilast.Controllers.StudentListController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

This is the error it dispplays
View is

Comment: You have not even shown the code where you call that method. And the error is self explanatory - you are not passing a value for `klasaid`

Comment: @StephenMuecke @Html.ActionLink("StudentList", "Index","StudentList", new { id=item.klasaid },null) |this is a link from index of klasaController

Comment: You have still not shown the view that contains the link that calls the `Index()` method of `StudentListController` or the controller method that generated that view (and how the model is populated)

Comment: Error comes when u access `ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="klsasaid")] int klasaid)`  so show your accessing code from where you call the index method with `klasaid`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I have is the StudentList View,just below the controller index above.but I have seen a tutorial in pluralsight when he does the same thing and works.here:[link]https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=mvc4-building&author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m5-data-ii&clip=2&mode=live

Comment: The only link in that view calls a `Create()` method, not the `Index()` method. We cannot help you unless you show the relevant code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I dont have one,thats why,thats all the code in my view and I have included a partial.The one in the vid works.If there is smth missing please tell so I can make it work.Thank

Comment: In a previous comment you said you have `@Html.ActionLink("StudentList", "Index","StudentList", new { id=item.klasaid },null)` - which view is that?, and more importantly what is the controller method that generates that view? - its that code that's the issue (your obviously not setting a value for `item.klasaid` - whatever that is

Comment: that link is in Klasa View.Klasa Controller Generates that view. public class Klasat2Controller : Controller
    {
        private udb db = new udb();

        //
        // GET: /Klasat2/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Keuni.ToList());
        }

Comment: and in the klasaView is @model IEnumerable<Unilast.Models.klasa>
and a foreach...

Comment: @StephenMuecke my goal is to list all students that are in that specific klass

Comment: You need to edit your question with the relevant code! (and try it with `return View(db.Keuni.Include(x => x.students).ToList());`

Comment: Should I add this at the Studentlist controller?@StephenMuecke Plus the x should be klasaid,thats the foreign key or just x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your controller like this

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {

        if (! id.HasValue || id.Value < 1 )
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        List<String> studentList = new List<string>();
        var klasa = _db.Keuni.FirstOrDefault(x => x.klasaid == id.Value);
        if (studentList != null)
        {
           return View(klasa);
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your student class **[ForeignKey("klasaid")]** needs to be placed above the declaration. you have placed it below.

Comment: I dont have a problem in my class structure.It works fine.I dont know why I cant show the studets that are enrolled in that class